# Facebook message send API

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to develop PHP Application through which I want to send message to any individual Facebook user.

I am using below API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/text-message

I am following this one while developing my app: http://www.phpgang.com/facebook-messenger-api-for-pages-using-curl-php_3929.html.

But when I am running my application it throws error:

```
  Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => (#100) 
  No matching user found [type] => OAuthException [code] => 100 
  [error_subcode] => 2018001 [fbtrace_id] => Ha3u2Mvk1ZF ) )
```

Please somebody help, I am stuck in this.

Comment: Seems like `OAuth` problem. Error says that `No matching user found`

Comment: I only want to developed php application with simple UI through which i want to send message to any individual. Please help with this.

Comment: I think you need to authenticate yourself before doing anything with FB API